# Is there a way to properly experiment with Solr field-types?

Tags: apache, testing, search, solr

I'm working with Solr for a basic search engine, and I've created a couple different `fieldTypes` that include various filters and tokenizers in their analyzer chains.

However, I'm finding it very difficult to assess how these components of the chain interact and when I query in the Solr Admin, I consistently get different results than I expect-- with no clue as to why.

Is there a way to see what a phrase like education:"x university" is being transformed into when I type it in the `q` section of the Admin?

Also, when the phrase goes through the chain can it be transformed into multiple things that are all searched or is it just a single modified phrase?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Analysis in Solr Admin to check how each field and its type process the tokens both while querying and indexing.

`Analyse Fieldname / FieldType:`

from the drop down option select field/type that you want to analyse and clieck on Analyse values.

ex: what tokenizer used, which all filter classes applied to token and how token is transformed after passing each filter class.

if 
`Verbose Output` is checked, it shows more details about each filter class used for the selected field/type.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial or set of resources outlining what things like "SGF" stand for? The docs seem to be somewhat scarce. Also, in the real search are more than just that field searched through? I made an education field that abbreviates school names (new york university -> nyu) but will this only search for nyu now, or also the original phrase?

Comment: Hover cursor on that `SGF` it shows which tokenizer/filter it is.